# Highlights and notes on PDF files gone missing

Tags: windows-10, pdf, pdf-reader, highlighting

I've been using the [Reader app](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows-8/reader-app-faq) to read, highlight and notes to PDF files on Windows 10 and it is being working well for a couple of weeks.

However, I just noticed the notes and highlights I added through this days have disappeared: They are not visible with Reader, FoxIt Reader or Acrobat Reader.

Any ideas of what might have happened? Where are the highlights/notes stored (in the PDF file or external files)?

Comment: Have you been saving the document after adding notes?

Comment: @Burgi it seems like it saves them automatically: I restarted my PC several times and they were there. Now, they are gone :S

Comment: While it worked, did it also work when you opened the files in Acrobat Reader?

Comment: @MaxWyss Yes, the highlights also appeared in Acrobat Reader